# Promises in ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I'm trying to write a class that has methods that return promises and promise chains. This attempt returns error from do_that()

I understand the problem with using 'this' which is why I used the self=this kludge, but I still get an error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

In addition to the question, how do I fix this, is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

    class myClass {

        constructor(name, pipeline) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        do_this() {
            var self = this;    // <-- yuck. Do I need this?
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function () { console.log("did this " + self.name);  resolve(self);  }, 1000);
            })
        }

        do_that() {
            var self = this;    // <-- yuck
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                setTimeout(function () { console.log("did that " + self.name);  resolve(self);  }, 1000);
            })
        }

        do_both() {
            return this.do_this().then(this.do_that);
        }

    }

    new myClass("myobj").do_both();  // <-- TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.
```

Comment: That's NOT a duplication....

Comment: This is not a duplication! Don't think you read the question.

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. It's just not about the function that you pass to  `new Promise` and to `setTimeout` (where you used `self` correctly), it's about passing `this.do_that` as a callback to `then` (in `do_both`).

Comment: For my money, the comment by Matt below regarding bindall() is the fully complete answer to my question. There is partial overlap with the other questions but it is not a duplicate which is why it has a different answer.

Answer (score 17):

This is what Arrow Functions are for:

```
 do_that() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => { console.log("did that " + this.name);  resolve(this);  }, 1000);
        })
    }
```

Comment: This partly answers the question. The other issue is `do_both` passes `this.do_that` to be called later unbounded. So either `return this.do_this().then(this.do_that.bind(this));` or `return this.do_this().then(x => this.do_that(x));` in that case

Comment: Thanks but still ugly. Can't I somehow retain the pretty Promise chain syntax dothis(obj).then(dothat) ?

Comment: @GroovyDotCom if your primary goal is "pretty" code, JavaScript may be the wrong language for you.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom you can bind your methods in the constructor: `this.do_that = this.do_that.bind(this);` - then you won't have to bind it anywhere else in the code. This pattern is common enough that utility libraries include functions like [`bindAll`](https://lodash.com/docs#bindAll) to make it easier.

Comment: Any pointers to explain why ES6 introduced Classes and didn't bind methods to "this" automatically?

Comment: @GroovyDotCom it didn't introduce classes, it introduced the `class` keyword as sugar for the existing constructor pattern. It doesn't do anything new under the hood.

Comment: I had a similar issue, this solution did the fix. Thanks for sharing @Mathletics